# PDO insert based on array keys as column names

Tags: php, pdo

I have a PDO insert statement that updates a database table from a form submission. There are many fields. I have purposely used the same column names as the html input names. Is there a cleaner way of laying out this code? Currently I have 30+ `$_POST` variables and would prefer a cleaner looking solution via a loop of some kind.

This is my current implementation, I've only included a few fields for example's sake.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable SET Col1 = ?, ColABC = ?, Col123 = ?, ColFoo = ?, ColDEF = ?");
$stmt->execute(
    array($_POST['Col1'], $_POST['ColABC'], $_POST['Col123'], $_POST['ColFoo'], $_POST['ColDEF'])
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like following

```
$postarr = array('Col1', 'ColABC', 'Col123', 'ColFoo', 'ColDEF'); //<---- defined all the form elements you like to get from post
$sql = ''; $param = array();
foreach($postarr as $k){
    $sql .= $k.'=:'.$k.','; // setting up placeholders for columns we are goign to update or get value from $_POST data
    $param[$k] = $_POST[$k]; // setting up param array argument for execute() function
}
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1); // <--- remove last ,
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable SET " . $sql);
$stmt->execute($param);
```

Comment: This doesn't escape the post variables so could leave the database open to SQL injection

Comment: A little more explanation would be helpful for the OP

Comment: @steve I have not assigned the values directly in the `insert` statement, whereas placeholders are used and actual values are sent as array in `execute` function. Hope it holds of SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

The following is not tested but you could perhaps try something like this.

```
<form id='sqlpost' method='post' action='/test/target.php'>
    <h1>SQL Post</h1>       
    <input type='text' name='user' value='fred'/>
    <input type='text' name='name' value='frederick'/>
    <input type='text' name='email' value='fred@bedrock.com'/>

    <input type='text' name='age' value='21'/>
    <input type='text' name='sex' value='male'/>

    <input type="submit" name="subform" value="Submit"/>
</form>


/*
target.php
----------
*/

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

    $known=array('user','email','name');
    $postdata=array();


    foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
        if( in_array( $field, $known ) ) $postdata[ $field ]=$value;
    }

    $keys=array_keys( $postdata );
    $values=array_values( $postdata );              

    $sql='insert into myTable (`'.implode('`,`',$keys).'`) values (:'.implode(':',$keys).')';
    echo $sql;
}
```

Comment: Could this potentially error if the column doesn't exist?

Comment: yep - the best bet would be to have an array of known field names and use something like `array_intersect` on the POST array to ensure the fields exist

Comment: Thanks, that would work. Does this solution protect from SQL injection as no bind method is used?

Comment: A slightly different version to address your concern regarding non-existent fields ~ uses an array of 'known' fields and ignores those that are not in that known fields array.

Answer (score -1):

get all value into an array $input. and use list() as followed.

```
$InputArray['cal1'] =  $_POST['cal1'];
$InputArray['collabc'] =  $_POST['collabc'];
$InputArray['col123'] =  $_POST['col123'];
$InputArray['clofoo'] =  $_POST['clofoo'];
$InputArray['coldef'] =  $_POST['coldef'];

if (count($inputArray) > 0) {
        while (list($key, $val) = each($inputArray)) {
            if(!empty($val)){
                $fields.= $key . ',';
                $valset.= "'". $val ."',";
            }
        }
    }   

    $fields = trim($fields, ',');
    $valset = trim($valset, ',');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($fields) VALUES ($valset)";

    $stmt = $this->dbCon->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($inputArray);
```