# how to map a class properties to corresponding fields in the database using mysqli in php

Tags: php, mysqli

If I have a class like this

```
class User {
    public $id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

}
```

how to map those properties to its corresponding database fields.

later , If I want to update a row, I can use something like this instead of passing some parameters to the update method

```
 $user->first_name="john";
    $user->update();
```

I have seen people are mapping object properties.

why and how to do it , I am new to OOP. please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is called "Object-relational mapping" (ORM). It is a technique (or design pattern) of accessing a relational database (like MySQL) from a code written in object-oriented way.

There are several popular PHP ORM libraries that you can use out-of-the-box to achieve what you described. ([doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) etc.) And most of the PHP frameworks come with a bundled ORM.

In case you want to try implemnting you own ORM in PHP as a lerning exercise, refer this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4034591/1125337).

Answer (score 0):

YOUR EXPECTED RESULT

```
 $InputArray['cal1'] =  $_POST['cal1'];
$InputArray['collabc'] =  $_POST['collabc'];
$InputArray['col123'] =  $_POST['col123'];
$InputArray['clofoo'] =  $_POST['clofoo'];
$InputArray['coldef'] =  $_POST['coldef'];

if (count($inputArray) > 0) {
        while (list($key, $val) = each($inputArray)) {
            if(!empty($val)){
                $fields.= $key . ',';
                $valset.= "'". $val ."',";
            }
        }
    }   

    $fields = trim($fields, ',');
    $valset = trim($valset, ',');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($fields) VALUES ($valset)";
```

REFER [PDO insert based on array keys as column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607148/pdo-insert-based-on-array-keys-as-column-names/34607389#34607389)